# How responsible are negative positioning on CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm getting started on CSS and I have the following question:

Is it "responsible" to use a negative positioning on CSS? Can this cause any conflict on browsers such as IE7,8? What do you recommend?

```
#example-bottom {
position: relative;
top: -3px;
min-height: 29px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}

Comment: I don't think that giving -ve value to an element will not be supported in IE7or8

Comment: @prashant:-All modern day browser(even IE7 or 8) support -ve margin!! :)

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi I am also saying same in my above comment ..

Comment: @prashant:- Ok got it..missed the **not** word!!! Sorry ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be implementation-specific limits.

From: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

All modern browsers (including IE7 and 8) support it, however there are some issues in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use the [negative margin](http://www.css-101.org/negative-margin/):-

> Negative top and left margins move the element up and left while
>   negative right and bottom margins make following siblings move left
>   and up.
>
> **Can this cause any conflict on browsers such as IE7,8?**

No there is no issue if you are using with any modern day browser.

Also [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/):-

> Negative margins are wholly supported across all modern browsers (and
>   IE6 in most cases).

**On a side note:-** There may be scenarios when negative margin can be a life saver, specially when you want to precisely position a div without having to use absolute or relative positioning